# Play 2.3 Scala: Explicitly passing Writer - needs to match Option{T] vs T; implicit writer can handle both

Tags: json, scala, playframework, implicit

I have a `case class` with a `json.Writes[T]` defined on it.

If I have an `Option[T]`, and with an `implicit` write in scope, I can call `Json.toJson(Option[T])`; and this works

However if I call `Json.toJson(T)(json.Writes[T])` - I get a compile error

*type mismatch;
 found   : play.api.libs.json.Writes[models.WorkflowTemplateMilestone]{def writes(o: models.WorkflowTemplateMilestone): play.api.libs.json.JsObject}
 required: play.api.libs.json.Writes[Option[models.WorkflowTemplateMilestone]]
 Note: implicit value workflowTemplateMilestoneAPIWrites is not applicable here because it comes after the application point and it lacks an explicit result type*

Am I passing the Writer in incorrectly? How does it work between `T` and `Option[T]` with the `implicit` write?

The actual code is below; in case I've mis diagnosed the issue

Custom writer

```
implicit val workflowTemplateMilestoneAPIWrites = new Writes[WorkflowTemplateMilestone] {
    def writes(o: WorkflowTemplateMilestone) = Json.obj(
        "id" -> o.id,
        "name" -> o.name,
        "order" -> o.order
      )
  }
```

WORKS

```
implicit val workflowTemplateMilestoneAPIWrites = new Writes[List[(WorkflowTemplate, Option[WorkflowTemplateMilestone])]] {
    def writes(l: List[(WorkflowTemplate, Option[WorkflowTemplateMilestone])]) = Json.obj(
      "id" -> l.head._1.id,
      "name" -> l.head._1.name,
      "milestones" ->
        l.map(o =>
          Json.toJson(o._2) **// Writer is picked up through Implict this WORKS**
        )
    )
  }
```

GIVES COMPILE ERROR

```
implicit val workflowTemplateMilestoneAPIWrites = new Writes[List[(WorkflowTemplate, Option[WorkflowTemplateMilestone])]] {
    def writes(l: List[(WorkflowTemplate, Option[WorkflowTemplateMilestone])]) = Json.obj(
      "id" -> l.head._1.id,
      "name" -> l.head._1.name,
      "milestones" ->
        l.map(o =>
          Json.toJson(o._2)**(WorkflowTemplateMilestone.workflowTemplateMilestoneAPIWrites)** // But if I explicitly pass in the Writer, I get the compile error
        )
    )
  }
```

Thanks,
Brent

Comment: To start, `def writes` should have an explicit result type, like the message says.  e.g. `def writes(o: WorkflowTemplateMilestone): JsValue = ...`

Comment: can the compiler not infer that for me?

Comment: See the warning you posted: **Note: implicit value workflowTemplateMilestoneAPIWrites is not applicable here because it comes after the application point and it lacks an explicit result type**.

Comment: Right - reading the error message; probably a good start.

Adding a return type doesn't change the message though. I thought I would try remove implicit; as I'm passing it in - but also no change.